# Can't upload EPS files in File Manager in ExpressionEngine 2.10.2

Tags: file-uploads

I am able to upload PDF, TXT, SQL, AI, XLSX, JPG, PNG files using the File Manager as a Super Admin. However, when I try to upload an EPS file, I get a "File not Allowed" error. Mime file has 'application/postscript', // .ai, .eps, .ps in the white list.

-- Does anyone else have any ideas? I have now tried installations of EE versions 1.6.8, 2.1.0, 2.7.0 and they load EPS files with no problems. There seems to be a problem uploading EPS files when I try EE 2.10.2, 3.0.6, 3.1.2. I wonder if it has something to do with the new Mime Types file from 2.10 onward? --

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have XSS filtering on for file uploads?

Comment: I have tried it both on and off.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on version, creation software used, possibly OS, and a whole host of other variables, the actual mime-type of a file can vary. Some quick research show me that an EPS file may represent as these mime types:

```
application/postscript
application/eps 
application/x-eps
image/eps
image/x-eps
```

I would try adding these mime types one-by-one to your white-list array and hopefully one will cover it. Make sure to remove the ones that didn't work after.

Comment: Thanks, I had already tried adding those mime-types, and it did not work. I also tried adding to the Apache mime file too.

Comment: FYI those are set in the /system/expressionengine/config/mimes.php file

Comment: Yes. I had set them in the correct place.